# Managing selenium server installation/configuration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Disclaimer: I'm really not familiar with setting up E2E, so hope I my questions are clear. The responsibility for setting up that environment at work has temporarily (hopefully) fallen on me.

We're testing Angular. I know that installing Protractor provides access to 'webdriver-manager', which takes care of setting up a selenium server.

Does doing so negate the need to install 'selenium-webdriver'?

The selenium-webdriver docs are good, but the protractor docs, not so much. I can't find a clear answer on what I would be missing by just following the protractor set up instructions. The way they are presented makes it sounds like you don't need to install anything else to get up and running with E2E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install `selenium-webdriver` manually - it would be installed alongside with `protractor`, since it is it's [dependency](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "request": "~2.36.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "2.45.1",
    ...
}
```

Note that after installing `protractor` you need to run:

```
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

FYI, [`webdriver-manager` is](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2cd7be86dbefa38cdb2ee6dd0ac4da1276b088b1/docs/tutorial.md#setup):

> A helper tool to easily get an instance of a Selenium Server running